# WARN in logcat ResourceType: For resource ..., entry index(...) is beyond type entryCount(1)

Tags: android, warnings, logcat, android-resources

I am getting these warnings on logcat every time the app renders some layout. Tried to search about but could not find a clue.

I think is something related with resources (drawables, strings or values) but I don't know what is causing this.

It's not an error, but is a little annoying.

Somebody have an idea?

```
04-22 15:28:33.204  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x01030128, entry index(296) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.204  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x01030224, entry index(548) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.204  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x01030005, entry index(5) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.204  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x01030237, entry index(567) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.204  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x0103000c, entry index(12) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x010301ed, entry index(493) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x010301f8, entry index(504) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x010301f9, entry index(505) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x010301fb, entry index(507) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x01030206, entry index(518) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x010301fa, entry index(506) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x010301fc, entry index(508) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x01030207, entry index(519) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x0103029d, entry index(669) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x01030467, entry index(1127) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x01030466, entry index(1126) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x01030465, entry index(1125) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x010301ed, entry index(493) is beyond type entryCount(1)
04-22 15:28:33.205  21943-21943/xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx W/ResourceType﹕ For resource 0x0103044b, entry index(1099) is beyond type entryCount(1)
```

Comment: I have have the almost same problem, only that I get spammed ONLY with "ResourceType: For resource 0x01030206, entry index(518) is beyond type entryCount(1)".

Comment: Have the same.. still looking for answers.

Comment: It start happens for me after upgrade gradle plugin from `3.1.4` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was custom theme applied with [Layers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lovejoy777.rroandlayersmanager) app

Comment: Nice direction, I will investigate my libs and try to see if there is some custom theme in them. I will accept this since there is no other answer